# Can I perform animations on a UIControl subclass with iPhone SDK 3.x?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation, uicontrol

I have a custom UIControl that passes UIControlEventValueChanged events back to my ViewController.  I also need to animate it (basic resizing) in certain circumstances, but UIControl seems to have no implementation of beginAnimations or commitAnimations.  Do I have to encase it in a UIView?  Any better solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UIControl is a UIView so you can just use the standard UIView calls.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[yourControl setFrame:theNewFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```